# Issue in displaying of SWT composite for RCP

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am creating a simple SWT container in my Eclipse RCP application and was having an issue with the location/order in which it is displayed. Here is the code I am using.

```java
@PostConstruct
public void createControls(Composite parent)
{
     parent.setBackground(new Color (Display.getCurrent (), 255, 144, 0));
     GridData parentData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
     parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
     parent.setLayoutData(parentData);
     Device device = Display.getCurrent ();
     Color backgroundColor = parent.getBackground();
     Color whiteColor = new Color (device, 255, 255, 255);
     Color randomColor = new Color (device, 255, 0, 0);

     final Composite criteriaContainer = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
     criteriaContainer.setBackground(randomColor);
     final GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
     final GridData comboGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false,1,1);

     criteriaContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
     criteriaContainer.setLayoutData(gridData);

     final Label primaryComboLabel = new Label(criteriaContainer, SWT.NONE);
     primaryComboLabel.setLayoutData(comboGridData);
     primaryComboLabel.setForeground(whiteColor);
     primaryComboLabel.setText("View by:");
     criteriaContainer.layout();
     criteriaContainer.pack();
     parent.layout();
     parent.pack();
}
```

I cant seem to get the label to appear at the top of the application(appears at the bottom center)[enter image description here][1]. If I write the same code and execute it as a standalone SWT application, the label appears at the top left.   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL312.png
Here is the difference when I have a standalone swt app.

```
public void showHistoryContainer() throws Exception {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display); 
        shell.setBackground(new Color (Display.getCurrent (), 255, 144, 0));
```

the rest of the code is the same. [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJmR6.png

Any ideas why this may be happening ?

Note: In my RCP application, I am not doing any other processing on my parent composite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the `createControls` is a part of. Is it an `MPart`?

I can't really reproduce this problem but there are a number of issues in your code which might be causing it.

**Never** change the Layout of a `Composite` passed to your code (`parent` here). Create another `Composite` as a child and set the layout on that.

Don't call `layout` and `pack`.

So simplifying your code I have:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent)
{
  Display device = parent.getDisplay();

  Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
  body.setBackground(new Color(device, 255, 144, 0));
  body.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  Color whiteColor = new Color(device, 255, 255, 255);
  Color randomColor = new Color(device, 255, 0, 0);

  Composite criteriaContainer = new Composite(body, SWT.BORDER);
  criteriaContainer.setBackground(randomColor);
  criteriaContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
  criteriaContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  Label primaryComboLabel = new Label(criteriaContainer, SWT.NONE);
  primaryComboLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
  primaryComboLabel.setForeground(whiteColor);
  primaryComboLabel.setText("View by:");
}
```

Finally if you create `Color` objects like this you must arrange to dispose of them or you will leak resources. If this is an e4 RCP you should use the CSS support instead.

Comment: thanks for your pointers. I wasn't planning to use Color, I only used it see the containers and why they werent appearing at the right place. (although I did not know about disposing them either, thanks)  Yes createControls is an MPart. I tried your code and my containers are still showing up from the bottom down. Still no idea why this is happening

Comment: so i figured out the issue. I did not post the code cause I was looking at the wrong class and I assumed it was not doing anything but I was passing the parent to another method which was adding a canvas to it. Sorry rookie mistake but thanks for the useful pointers.